# Regext start with 3 consecutive capital letters

Tags: regex

Have the following regex to detect a file start with 3 consecutive capital letters:

```
(?=(.*[A-Z]){3})(?=(.*[a-z]){3})(?=.*(_|[^\w]))
```

When I search a file I found it:

```
root@node01:~# find . -type f -name DASD-680.mp4.part
./DASD-680.mp4.part
```

But when I search didn't found any results:

```
root@RPI01:~# find . -type f -regextype egrep -regex "(?=(.*[A-Z]){3})(?=(.*[a-z]){3})(?=.*(_|[^\w]))"
```

What's the exactly problem???

Update:

file exists:

```
TAD-007.mp4
```

but no result with this:

```
/usr/bin/find . -type f -regextype posix-extended -regex "[A-Z]{3}.*"
```

thanks!

Comment: I don't know what your regex is doing but definitely it's not looking for 3 consecutive capital letters anywhere. why do you use look-ahead? test your regex here: https://regex101.com/

Comment: Something like `[A-Z]{3}.*` is probably what you're looking for. That regex you have looks like it's meant for something else entirely

Comment: `egrep` does not support lookaheads and PCRE regexps like the one you have. Also, it must match the whole path.

Comment: regex is half way for pasworks

Comment: @user no results with this [A-Z]{3}.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `find` gives list of files prefixed with `./` like `./DASD-680.mp4.part`
- the regex motif must match the whole filename, included `./`
- the regex flavor doesn't support quantifiers

Here is a way to do what you want:

```
find . -type f -regex '..[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z].*'
```

where the first 2 dots matches `./`

You cal also use:

```
find . -type f -regex '\./[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z].*'
```